# How are the results passed from a chrome.storage.sync callback? Clarity needed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, google-chrome-storage

I am making a chrome extension that pulls information from storage and passes the results into the callback function. I am new to javascript and don't understand where the results variable is coming from.

This below function requests a value from a key in the chrome storage:

```
function getProjectList(callbackfunc) { 
    chrome.storage.sync.get('proj_list', callbackfunc);
}
```

This will be my callback function:

```
function alertResult(results){
    alert(results.key);
}
```

Calling the functions:

```
getProjectList(alertResult);
```

My questions is, why is there a 'results' argument in the alertResult function? It can be named anything, but whatever argument name I enter is the results from the chrome.storage.sync.get request.

Why does it suddenly appear only in that function? How does javascript "know" that the first argument is the result of the chrome request?

I am asking because I want to pass an additional variable into the alertResult function but can't seem to because I think there can only be 1 results argument.

I would like to say the below function, but it doesn't work. So I want to know why there can only be one argument in this function.

```
function alertResult(results, newVar){
    alert(results.key);
    alert(newVar);
}
```

Can someone shine some light on this for me? New to javascript so a lot is still fuzzy.

Comment: The first argument to `getProjectList` is named `callbackfunc` — how does javascript know that? If you add a second named argument but only call it with one argument, what happens?

Comment: So why does it only accept once variable? If I add another variable, how would it know which are the results? Can it only accept one variable?